# Why float values can be found only as text in where conditions

Tags: sql, postgresql

Why it can not find the row if argument is not quoted?

```
CREATE TABLE test (id integer, value real);
INSERT INTO test VALUES (1, 0.1);
```

Does not work:

```
SELECT * FROM test where value = 0.1;
 id | value
----+-------
(0 rows)
```

Works!

```
SELECT * FROM test where value = '0.1';
 id | value
----+-------
  1 |   0.1
(1 row)
```

Comment: Unrelated, but: you should not compare apples to oranges. `0.1` is a number, `'0.1'` is a string (text) constant. You should always compare columns to literals of the same type. Do not rely on the evil implicit data type conversion.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Actually a quoted value in SQL isn't necessarily a string. Its type is inferred for example from the column type it is compared to. You can see that when you explain the query. But in unquoted case the value is treated as `double precision` instead and `0.1::real` is not the same as `0.1::double precision` (both aren't exactly 0.1). `select 0.1::real::double precision;` returns `0.100000001490116`.

Comment: @Tometzky: a single quoted value **is** a string. But then the database tries to convert that string to something else. But it starts out as a string. Relying on implicit data type conversion is always a bad idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should avoid [inexact data types(like `real`)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/datatype-numeric.html):

> Inexact means that some values cannot be converted exactly to the
>   internal format and are stored as approximations, so that storing and
>   retrieving a value might show slight discrepancies. Managing these
>   errors and how they propagate through calculations is the subject of
>   an entire branch of mathematics and computer science and will not be
>   discussed here, except for the following points:
>
> - If you require exact storage and calculations (such as for monetary amounts), use the numeric type instead.
> - If you want to do complicated calculations with these types for anything important, especially if you rely on certain behavior in
>     boundary cases (infinity, underflow), you should evaluate the
>     implementation carefully.
> - Comparing two floating-point values for equality might not always work as expected.

If you insist on using real make sure both arguments have the same data type:

```
SELECT * FROM test where value = 0.1::real;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=8d4d0fe94d9196c85dce1764453492c6)**